# Lighting a 2d city in Grease Pencil using a shader

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I'm drawing a 2d city in Grease Pencil. I'm wondering if there is a way to light the city using Shaders? Or should I just use an actual 3d light or lighter-colored brushstrokes to achieve the desired effect? Below are some examples of what I'd like to do.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Both ways work (light objects VS manually drawn lighting). Is your question about which method to choose ?

Comment: Yes. I'm wondering which method would be more effective.

Comment: Both are effective. It depends on the creative direction you want to take, your skills in each domain, ... I don't think there is a good answer to your question.

Comment: I'm aiming for a Sci-Fi type kind of city in the background of a drawing.

Answer (score 2):

Your example images show a very specific kind of glowing effect/vaporwave of lighting that is being suggested in what you want to illustrate. In CGI terminology, this lighting effect is called, **Bloom**. For Blender, there is one and currently only one method to create this effect.

In your grease pencil object, select the strokes/fills that you want to light up in your scene and move them to a *new layer*.

[image]

With this new layer selected, we will convert it into a mesh by going to `Object` $\rightarrow$ `Convert` $\rightarrow$ `Bezier Curve`. Grease Pencil objects can’t directly convert into meshes so; we must convert them into curves before we can convert them into meshes. Now we can go to `Object` $\rightarrow$ `Convert` $\rightarrow$ `Polygon Curve`. In *Edit mod*e, fill the mesh curves with faces.

[image]

**Bloom** can only be applied to emission materials. Shader materials are different from Grease Pencil materials. Shaders need to be applied to mesh faces to be shown in our renders. Hence, why we had to duplicate our Grease Pencil strokes/fills into mesh faces.

Next, we need to move our newly generated mesh into a new scene. Make sure you have a new separate scene created by going to the top right corner. Go to `Object` $\rightarrow$ `Link/Transfer Data` $\rightarrow$ `Link Objects to Scene` $\rightarrow$ *select your new scene*; to move your mesh into the newly created scene. You can delete the mesh from your original scene by unlinking the object and deleting the copy.

[image]

Now, we can finally apply the bloom. In your new scene, go to `Properties` -> `Render Settings` -> *and select* `Bloom`. To create a basic emission material, we can use the shader node or switch to emission in the *Materials Properties* tab. For my example, I copied my grease pencil material *HEX* color to paste into my emission color and adjusted the emission strength to $30$.

[image]

This option only works with the Eevee rendering engine. To show bloom in cycles, we must use the `Glare node` in the *Compositor* workspace. Even though, I just mentioned a different method to create bloom, it doesn’t change the fact that we still need the emission material to accomplish this.

In either scene, go into the *Compositor* workspace. With the *Transparent* background selected in the properties tab, use an `Alpha Over` node to place your new scene over your old scene.

[image]

The result is as shown. **Bloom** is considered a post effect within Blender. Likewise, so is Grease Pencil. In case you didn’t know, grease pencil always renders first in front of the camera before any other post effect. Hence, why we had to separate the mesh into a new, different scene and, why we needed the compositor to control the order of post effects rendered.

[image]

Additionally, in `Object Properties` -> `Visibility` -> *I unchecked* `Use Lights` for the grease pencil object to control how the grease pencil renders and I did a little more modeling for the mesh then I had previously demonstrated. For any more additional properties that I could have omitted, below is the blend file of my example.

[image]
*Blender 4.0.2*